# How to intelligently remove similar parts out of a set of strings?

Tags: python, html, parsing, nlp

For example, this is what I want to input:

```
input = [
   '<html><head><title>Albert Einstein - Minipedia</title></head><body><b>Welcome to Minipedia! You are viewing page 1</b> Albert Einstein was a scientist</body></html>',
   '<html><head><title>Ludwig Van Beethoven - Minipedia</title></head><body><b>Welcome to Minipedia! You are viewing page 2</b> Ludwig van Beethoven was a Musician</body></html>',
   '<html><head><title>Red - Minipedia</title></head><body><b>Welcome to Minipedia! You are viewing page 3</b> Red is a color.</body></html>'
]
```

and what I'm looking for as output is:

```
output = [
    ['Albert Einstein', 'Albert Einstein was a scientist'],
    ['Ludwig Van Beethoven', 'Ludwig Van Beethoven was a musician'],
    ['Red', 'Red is a color']
]
```

The logic I'm looking for approximately that if there are substrings of each document that have significant overlap (i.e. small enough edit distance), they should be taken out and used to tokenize the remaining strings that have sufficient difference.

Are there any libraries for this?

Comment: If you’re interested in making the library, we can help. If you’re interested in finding one, it’s off-topic.

Comment: To be more explicit: If you’re trying to solve a problem and you’re comfortable with writing the code on your own, [edit] your question to remove the library mention, include what you tried and what the specific problem with your code is. Or if the problem is the algorithm itself, try to come up with your own and point out its flaws.

Comment: May I ask what is the correct place to ask this question? I'm interested in making the library if it doesn't exist, but if someone has already invented this wheel I'd rather not re-invent it, especially given that this is probably a common problem to many web scraping applications.

Comment: Scrapers often use just regexes (see [tag:regex]), AFAIK. If you want something more general, functioning for a broad class of pages having a similar but not exactly the same structure, you’ll have to describe the structure more generally than you did. Focus on the actual problem you’re trying to solve, not an oversimplified attempt to solve one of its parts.

Comment: If you avoid the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/238706) and describe the actual problem, you can get a library recommendation as part of an answer that explains how that library works. Just don’t ask directly for a library here. We don’t know where you should ask about libraries – there is Google, there are forums all over the Internet, try. The best option around here is [SoftwareRecs.SE], but note that its scope is very limited and you should read its help center first before posting a question there.